# Implement a health endpoint to check if an API is up and running as expected

Tags: asp.net, api, health-monitoring

I am wondering what is the best way to check if an API is up and running as expected. This check would need to occur at regular intervals, similar to what the author of this blog speaks of:

http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2009/add-a-heartbeat-method-to-your-service

Is this the best practice for monitoring API status?

Comment: You could simply just do a GET to your API on an interval to check if it's online.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That does seem like the simplest way of doing so, is this method widely used?  Would I need to get an overall picture of the systems health as in connectivity to external dependencies (i.e. brokers, external services) or would your suggestion satisfy this monitoring requirement?

Comment: It would largely depend on what you wanted to report with your heartbeat API. You could check status of various parts of your system and then return that in the API response. If you were to get anything other than a 200 OK from your API, that would raise an error. Also, you could raise an error if any of your systems don't report good status from the API response.